# Theme with a sidebar?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sidebar

Is there a twitter bootstrap theme with a sidebar showing ToC of the current page, like the right one here: http://ruhoh.com/docs/2

I like the affix+scrollspy stack, but If You have a lot of headings You can't see them all, since You can't scroll affix's sidebar.

Bootstrap docs suffer from the same issue:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup! Check out the following:

- http://startbootstrap.com/simple-sidebar : This is a sidebar theme
- http://startbootstrap.com/modern-business : This is a full site theme and one of it's pages has a decent sidebar, i.e, http://startbootstrap.com/templates/modern-business/sidebar.html

In both cases, you will have to add scrollspy on your own though.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the pre-scrollable class?

try to go to bootstrap page and put the class after the affix class

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#progress

the div should look like this

```
<div class="bs-sidebar hidden-print affix pre-scrollable" role="complementary">
```

It will have a scroolbar on sidebar.